I want to protect certain cells in an excel using the npm package XLSX
The problem however is that the only way to do it is using the ws['!protect'] attribute to the whole sheet and then traverse through each cell one by one and set it as:
worksheet1[cellAddress].s = { protection: { locked: false } };

This however doesn't work and it always locks the whole sheet. I need something like to protect an exact cell and not the whole sheet.
Can someone help me on this?
